# ROS2 topic "statustext" doesn't execute

Tags: c++, ros, ros2

I want to see some status messages from my drone using "ros2 topic echo /mavros/statustext/recv" in the terminal.

After subscription, I just waiting for a message,(in this time my drone do mission, do takeoff, do landing...) but there's nothing received in that topic.

How to get any message in this topic?

Comment: You need to provide it a valid topic name. What does `ros2 topic list` produce?

Comment: it has this topic

Comment: Then the most likely cause is that the topic isn't actually being publish on.

Comment: Yeah, that is problem. For some reason mavros topic "statustext" don't publish something at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ros2 param set /mavros/sys heartbeat_mav_type "GCS"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).